# How to restore a paragraph to previous state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small web tool that helps in creating metadata for images that can be easily used in html description and viewed for details later on.

The current state of the tool/app is perfect except for one fact, and that is the following: I would like to be able to revert the state of the changed paragraph once I click the button "Back" so I can fix any missing fields or remove unwanted ones and then update it to the new state without redoing the whole process

I can't share the specific area of the code, because I don't have such a call for the back button, I'd like to know if it would be posible with javascript?

The only thing that I am using in the back button call now is the switch between visible divs:

```
//Switch divs on button click
    function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('inputmeasurements')) {

                if (document.getElementById('inputmeasurements').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('inputmeasurements').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('finishedmeasurements').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('inputmeasurements').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('finishedmeasurements').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle of the tool: https://jsfiddle.net/7r9zdcvo/

Currently the "Convert" button uses these calls (and switch visible divs too which is mentioned above):

```
//Convert input into formated metadata
function myFunction5() {
  var m1 = document.getElementById("m1")
  var str = m1.innerHTML
  var fields = [
    { regex: /B1/g, id:"bust"},
    { regex: /W1/g, id:"waist"},
    { regex: /H1/g, id:"hips"},
    { regex: /L1/g, id:"lng"},
    { regex: /S1/g, id:"shl"},
    { regex: /S2/g, id:"slv"},
    { regex: /I1/g, id:"ins"},
    { regex: /TITLE/g, id:"title"},
    { regex: /SPECIFICS/g, id:"specifics"},
    { regex: /MERC/g, id:"mercedes"},
    { regex: /SUPPLIER/g, id:"supplier"},
    { regex: /DATE/g, id:"date"},
    { regex: /WEIGHT/g, id:"weight"}]

  for (o of fields){
    var val = document.getElementById(o.id).value
    if (val != "")
      str = str.replace(o.regex, val)
    else // remove line
      str = str.replace(
        new RegExp("\\s+"+(typeof o.regex=='string'?o.regex:o.regex.source)+".*?\n")
        ,'')
  }
  m1.innerHTML = str;
}

//Convert input into formated metadata
function myFunction6() {
  var m1 = document.getElementById("m1")
  var str = m1.innerHTML
  var fields = [
    { regex: /B2/g, id:"bust"},
    { regex: /W2/g, id:"waist"},
    { regex: /H2/g, id:"hips"},
    { regex: /L2/g, id:"lng"},
    { regex: /S3/g, id:"shl"},
    { regex: /S4/g, id:"slv"},
    { regex: /I2/g, id:"ins"},
    { regex: /SPEC2/g, id:"specifics"},
    { regex: /SUPP2/g, id:"supplier"},
    { regex: /DAT2/g, id:"date"},
    { regex: /WGT2/g, id:"weight"}]

  for (o of fields){
    var val = document.getElementById(o.id).value
    if (val != "")
      str = str.replace(o.regex, val)
    else // remove line
      str = str.replace(
        new RegExp("\\s+"+(typeof o.regex=='string'?o.regex:o.regex.source)+".*?\n")
        ,'')
  }
  m1.innerHTML = str;
}
```

It converts the entered data entered within the inputs/text areas in this div:

```
<div id="inputmeasurements">
                        <p id="topmeasurement" align=left>
                        <input type="text" class="topm" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="Weight"><br>
                        <input type="text" class="topm" id="supplier" name="supplier" placeholder="Supplier"><br>
                        <input type="text" class="topm" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date"><br>
                        <textarea class="topm" id="specifics" name="specifics" placeholder="Specifics" style="height: 30px;"></textarea><br>
                        <textarea class="topm" id="mercedes" placeholder="Enter Any Aditional Data Here"></textarea><br>
                        <textarea type="text" class="topm" id="title" name="title" maxlength="80" placeholder="TITLE" style="height: 30px;"></textarea><span id="counter"></span><br><br>                      
                        </p>
                        <p id="botmeasurement">
                        <input type="text" class="botm" id="bust" name="bust">&nbsp;Bust<br>
                        <input type="text" class="botm" id="waist" name="waist">&nbsp;Waist<br>
                        <input type="text" class="botm" id="hips" name="hips">&nbsp;Hips<br>
                        <input type="text" class="botm" id="lng" name="lenght">&nbsp;Lenght<br>
                        <input type="text" class="botm" id="shl" name="shoulders">&nbsp;Shoulders<br>
                        <input type="text" class="botm" id="slv" name="sleeves">&nbsp;Sleeves<br>
                        <input type="text" class="botm" id="ins" name="inseam">&nbsp;Inseam<br>
                        </p>
                        <div id="enter-meta-wrap">
                            <p style="text-align: center;">Convert measurements to html ready metadata</p> 
                            <button id="enter-meta" onclick="myFunction5();myFunction6();switchVisible();">Convert</button>
                            <button id="new-meta" onclick="myFunction3()">New</button>
                        </div>
        </div>
```

...into the paragraph within this div:

```
<div id="finishedmeasurements">
            <table id="grid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr onclick="clipboard(this);">
                    <td>
                        <p id="m1" align=center>
                        bB2 wW2 hH2 lL2 shS3 slvS4 insI2 | SPEC2 | SUPP2 | DAT2 | WGT2 <br><br>
                        TITLE<br>
                        SPECIFICS<br>
                        SUPPLIER | DATE | WEIGHT<br><br>
                        MERC<br><br>
                        B1 Bust inches flat&lt;/br&gt;<br>
                        W1 Waist inches flat&lt;/br&gt;<br>
                        H1 Hips inches flat&lt;/br&gt;<br>
                        L1 Length &lt;/br&gt;<br>
                        S1 Shoulders &lt;/br&gt;<br>
                        S2 Sleeves &lt;/br&gt;<br>
                        I1 Inseam &lt;/br&gt;<br>
                        &lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
                    <div id="new-meta-wrap">
                        <p style="text-align: center;">Convert measurements to html ready metadata</p>
                        <button id="go-back" onclick="switchVisible();">Back</button>
                        <button id="new-meta" onclick="myFunction3()">New</button>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please simplify your fiddle to only what's necessary to demonstrate this particular problem. It's cumbersome to try and work within your entire app. Also, move your script to the JavaScript panel and use the TidyUp button.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I don't see any.

Comment: I have updated my questions with relevant code parts and javascript functions, I hope that can be of any help.

Updating the fiddle and placing the script to the javascript panel makes it broken somehow...